# Strange behaviour of SolrCloud Backup on local FS

Tags: solr, backup, solrcloud

[solr 8.11.1 with 4 nodes and Zookeeper-Assembly]

i try to do backup on local fs as follows:

1. put `<str name="allowPaths">*</str>` in solr.xml
2. create server/butest2-dir on each node
3. curl 'http://XXX:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=testback2&collection=backuptest&location=butest2'
   Solr will try now to do backup and place it on each server, am I right?
   But I get:

````
    "XXX:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at null: Failed to backup core=backuptest_shard3_replica_n10 because java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /XXX/solr-8.11.1/server/butest2/testback2/backuptest"},
  "Operation backup caused exception:":"java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /XXX/solr-8.11.1/server/butest2/testback2/backuptest/zk_backup_0",
"exception":{
    "msg":"/XXX/solr-8.11.1/server/butest2/testback2/backuptest/zk_backup_0",
    "rspCode":-1},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"/XXX/solr-8.11.1/server/butest2/testback2/backuptest/zk_backup_0",
...```


At the same time if i use another instance of SolrCloud

[solr 8.11.1 with 2 nodes and Zookeeper as standalone] 

I can do backup and it is saved on one certain node I call in URL.

Something goes wrong and I cannot find any explanation.

Thanks a lot
Katja
````

Comment: I could do the backup after performing mkdir -p /XXX/solr-8.11.1/server/xxx/test2/btest/zk_backup_0 and mkdir -p /XXX/solr-8.11.1/server/xxx/test2/btest/shard_backup_metadata/ on each node, but it still not what I need. How can I define the node which fs will be used for backup storage?